# Left and Right in a li to have a border

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a li that gets generated dynamically and I want the left li and the right li to have a border. I was thinking of adding a classes to them. The li that has class "hidden" doesnt get displayed. The list might be like this

```
<li class="show">First</li>
<li class="hidden">Second</li>
<li class="hidden">Third</li>
<li class="show">Fourth</li>
```

Or

```
<li class="hidden">First</li>
<li class="hidden">Second</li>
<li class="show">Third</li>
<li class="show">Fourth</li>
```

No matter what how they are stacked, the first list should have a border on the left and last list should have border on the right.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/403tLzn9/5/)

Comment: Why don't you just put the border radius on the ul?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$('ul').each(function() {
    $(this).find("li.show:first").addClass('first');
    $(this).find("li.show:last").addClass('last');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/manantwar/95yn2za4/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can also put the border radius on the `ul` instead of using any js at all

http://jsfiddle.net/403tLzn9/6/

```
.stackbar {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px !important;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px !important;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px !important;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px !important;
    background-color: #cD3e25;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also your js doesn't work is because you are trying to find the `li` inside of your `li`

Comment: Thank you. I will give this another option